# Running MVC application on IIS behaves differently than on running Visual studio localhost

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc application deployed as application under one website in IIS.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<SelectListItem> ddlCountry = countryService.GetCountries().Select(d => new SelectListItem() { Text = d.Name, Value = d.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
    ddlCountry.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = string.Empty, Value = string.Empty });
    ViewData["ddlCountry"] = ddlCountry;
}

public ActionResult GetCities(int Id)
{
    if (!Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InDev"]))
    {
        return Redirect("http://example.com/");
    }
    var list = cityService.GetCities(Id).Select(d => new {Id = d.Id, Name = d.Name }).ToList();
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View:**

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, "Country Name")</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ViewData["ddlCountry"] as List<SelectListItem>)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId, "City Name")</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityId, ViewData["ddlCity"] as List<SelectListItem>)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId)</td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#CountryId').change(function () {
        loadDropDown("CityId", "BookingRequest/GetCities/" + $('#CountryId').val())
        $('#AreaId').html($('<option></option>').val("").html(""));
    });

    function loadDropDown(destinationId, Url) {
        $.getJSON(Url, function (data) {
            $('#' + destinationId).html($('<option></option>').val("").html(""));
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                $('#' + destinationId).append(
                     $('<option></option>').val(item.Id).html(item.Name)
                 );
            });
        });
    }
});
```

When I deployed it to IIS as an application under website it loads the cities properly. URL was like `http://www.example.com/applicationname/BookingRequest`. and When I change the country dropdown value it executes get on `http://www.example.com/applicationname/BookingRequest/GetCities/2` and all things are working fine.

but when I hit run on the visual studio it and change the country it executes getCities on wrong URL: `http://localhost:506084/BookingRequest/BookingRequest/GetCities/2`

My question is why this behaves differently on the localhost running from the visual studio and on the IIS? Is it due to the deployment as web application inside the website at IIS? Or is it anything to do with my browser?

Here is snap of that request from web developer tool of IE.

[image]

Comment: You not passing the correct (relative) url. Follow standard practice and use `'@Url.Action("GetCities", "BookingRequest")'` so your url' will be generated correctly (in this case with the leading slash - `/BookingRequest/GetCities`

Comment: @StephenMuecke But that ajax call are in different javascript file. So how would I use `@URL` helper to generate the url in javascript file. Is Jinesh's answer below considered to be best practice to use?

Comment: You can do it like that, although the most common solution is to add the url to the elements `data-` attributes - e.g. `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ...... new { data_url = "Url.Action("..", "..") })` and then access it the `change()` event - e.g. `var url = $(this).data(url);`

Comment: In project properties > Web > Click radio button "Use Local IIS Server" . By doing this your both behaviours will be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the correct relative path in MVC below are the following thing we need to do.

**In MVC View :**

```
<script>
var strUrl = '@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")';
</script>
```

**In Javascript:**

Get that variable "strUrl" and use in your ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: strUrl ,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "html",
 success: function (data) {

});
```

Comment: Although I would go with the solution mentioned by the Stephen in the comment to the question, I liked the way you are passing url to the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you have entered the wrote url for IIS Express in your Project settings.

Open the Properties of your Web project and go to the "Web" tab and change the "Project Url" to from `http://localhost:506084/BookingRequest/` to `http://localhost:506084/` or `http://localhost:506084/applicationname` for the sake of it.

But it doesn't matter if it's in a application folder or not, urls in MVC Webapps should always be relative to application path (using `~/Relative/Url/Here`).

That being said... don't hardcode your root url inside your code. Use `return Redirect("/")` (domain root) or `return Redirect("~/")` (application root).

Comment: My project URL is : http://localhost:50684/. I totally agree with your comment MVC treats all request relative to application path. but then why am I getting such a weird behaviour?

Comment: Is `BookingRequest` your controller and your java script embeded in the same controller? Then you don't need the `BookingRequest` in `BookingRequest/GetCities` as part of your java script url, since you're already on the right page. Otherwise you have to go from application root if you access it from other controllers/actions

Comment: Yes javascript file is on the same page but If I remove BookingRequest from the url part it works fine under visual studio but then stop working at IIS because URL would be like `http://www.example.com/applicationname/GetCities/2`. :(

Comment: @jenish - When solution run under iis express it temporary host application on some port and runs as website and if same application we deploy as virtual directory then path problem will come.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Decided to go with solution mentioned in comment by stephen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the base url of you application. To do that, you need to add  tag on each of your pages or may on _Layout page.

For example:

```
<base href="Root URL of you aplication" />
```

Please note that this should match the root url you are seeing the browser.

This way your application will always refer to correct root path.

Comment: It seems you were unsure of this answer, or you posted it, and did not finish.  Perhaps you want to delete this answer?